# How to make MediaRecorder outputs streambale?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, mp4, mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder to record the webcam like this :

```
 let options
        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs=h264')) {
            options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=h264' };
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs=vp9')) {
            options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs=vp8')) {
            options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp8' };
        } else {
            options = {
                mimeType: 'video/mp4', audioBitsPerSecond: 128 * 1000,
                videoBitsPerSecond: 1 * 1000 * 1000
            };
        }
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream, options);
        recorder.start(500)
```

And I am not able to use `video/mp4` as mime type because is not supported by the browsers so I am using `video/webm` instead. The output file is in chunks and the playback is really smooth yet I am not able to play it online unless it is fully loaded. I decided to add FFMPEG into the process and used `ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4` but the result is the same. My understanding is that `MediaRecorder` is recording in chunks that has no MOOV atom to begin with therefore there is no MOOV to be brought to the beginning of the file. How can I generate MOOV for `video/webm`? Will having MOOV make my file streambale or playable at buffer at all?

Here is a sample of my file :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I am not able to use video/mp4 as mime type because is not supported by the browsers so I am using video/webm instead.

Well, the file you show in your hex editor is definitely MP4/ISOBMFF, and not WebM/Matroska.  Are you saying that's the file you're getting after your FFmpeg process, or the one straight out of MediaRecorder?

> The output file is in chunks and the playback is really smooth yet I am not able to play it online unless it is fully loaded.

Normally, playback will be fine without seeking... it's seeking that's the problem since the player doesn't know how long/big the elements are as they have indefinite size due to the MediaRecorder output being streamed.  Much like you're doing with MP4, you can do the same with WebM:

```
ffmpeg -i original.webm -c copy fixed.webm
```

> How can I generate MOOV for video/webm?

There is no such thing in WebM/Matroska.

Comment: Yes, I am converting webm to mp4 on the server through :  ffmpeg().input(stream).videoCodec('libx264').audioCodec('aac').format('mp4').outputOptions([
            "-movflags",
            "frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart",
            "-preset",
            "veryfast",
            "-crf",
            "32",
            "-threads 5", ) is there anyway I can do ffmpeg -i original.webm -c copy fixed.webm and all the options above in one go? Thanks for the answer by the way, you helped a lot.